# Why cannot I call sublime Text editor 2 from terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, sublimetext2

I tried this

```
Muhammeds-MacBook-Pro:first_app muhammedz786$ subl Gemfile
-bash: subl: command not found
```

Why is this happening?
I also tried this

```
Muhammeds-MacBook-Pro:first_app muhammedz786$ subl ~/.gemrc
-bash: subl: command not found
```

Please help

Comment: is `subl` in your PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command from Terminal:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin/subl
```

and you should be able to use the `subl` command. If you are using Sublime Text 3, the command is

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/bin/subl
```